# How to build form using data dynamically in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning vue.js. I am trying to build a form dynamically from data. The form is condition based. If I select some field from the select field the specific content related to that option has to show.

**Here is the data**

If the model of "id: 2" object is "germany", the show from "id: 3" has to become true and the show from 'id:4" and "id: 5" has to become false.

Similarly, If the model of "id: 2" object is "us", the show from the id: 4 has to become true and the show from "id:3" and "id: 5" has to become false.

```
  data(){
    return{
      fields: [
        {
          id: 1,
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Name",
          model: "",
          show: true
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          type: "select",
          placeholder: "Select",
          model: "",
          show: true,
          options: [
            {value: "germany", text: "Gemany", id: "germany"},
            {value: "us", text: "United States", id: "us"},
            {value: "uk", text: "United Kingdom", id: "uk"}
          ],
          events: "onChange"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          type: "paragraph",
          text: "Berlin",
          show: false
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          type: "paragraph",
          text: "New York",
          show: false
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          type: "paragraph",
          text: "London",
          show: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**Here is template**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="" v-for="field in fields" :key="field.id">
      <input :type="field.type" :placeholder="field.placeholder" v-model="field.model" :id="field.id" v-if="field.type == 'text' && field.show">
      <select v-model="field.model" :id="field.id" v-if="field.type == 'select' && field.show" @change="onChange(field.id)">
        <option v-for="option in field.options" :key="option.id" :value="option.value" :id="option.id">{{option.text}}</option>
      </select>
      <p v-if="field.type == 'paragraph' && field.show" :id="field.id">{{field.text}}</p>
    </div>
    <button @click="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

**methods**

```
onChange(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: What is stored in `fields` is not JSON. It it is just a regular object. JSON is a string.

Comment: In the onChange event you can say: this.fields.filter(field => field.id === 3) .show = this.fields.filter(field => field.id === id).model === 'germany' and follow a similar pattern

Comment: You're missing a crucial link: there is no mapping between the cities and countries. How are you going to infer that relationship?

Comment: How to link between the objects. My knowledge is very basic.

Comment: @Terry how to map between cities and countries? Help

Answer (score 1):

`v-model` on select does the job to find the selected value.

First, you can add an new property (`option_id` for example) to create a link between your option field `id` and your paragraph field `option_id`.
Then add a `selectedOptionId` data used for `v-model` to reach the right selected field.

You can now put this selected field out of the `v-for` loop and remove the `show` and `model` properties:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return{
      selectedOptionId: '',
      fields: [
        {
          id: 1,
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Name",
          model: "",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          type: "select",
          placeholder: "Select",
          options: [
            {value: "germany", text: "Gemany", id: "germany"},
            {value: "us", text: "United States", id: "us"},
            {value: "uk", text: "United Kingdom", id: "uk"}
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          option_id: "germany",
          type: "paragraph",
          text: "Berlin",
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          option_id: "us",
          type: "paragraph",
          text: "New York",
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          option_id: "uk",
          type: "paragraph",
          text: "London",
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selectedField(){
      return this.fields.find(field =>  field.option_id == this.selectedOptionId)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="field in fields" :key="field.id">
      <input :type="field.type" :placeholder="field.placeholder" v-model="field.model" :id="field.id" v-if="field.type == 'text'">
      <select v-model="selectedOptionId" :id="field.id" v-if="field.type == 'select'">
        <option v-for="option in field.options" :key="option.id" :value="option.id" :id="option.id">{{option.text}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <p v-if="selectedField" :id="selectedField.id">{{selectedField.text}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what if we  have multiple selects?

Comment: @KiranVilla you can use `multiple` on [select](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select). Just change the `v-model` type to array and the computed property: [fiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/15L2wzfe/)

Comment: My intention is to build a form using several objects which contains several select types. There may be several selects in the form (for ex. one select for country, other select for state, etc) if I select a specific option from the countries, the result has to show below that select field similarly for state also. Right now in the fiddle example it is showing out side loop. Hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution: in your data you could add a variable `idToShowMain`, which is an array of id you want to show. You will initialize it with the default visualization:

```
idToShowMain: [ 1,2 ],
```

Then in your options you will add a property for each item with the array related to that option. When the value changes you will replace the main array with the one selected.

```
options: [
    {value: "germany", text: "Gemany", id: "germany", idToShow: [ 1,2,3 ] },
    {value: "us", text: "United States", id: "us", idToShow: [ 1,2,4 ] },
    {value: "uk", text: "United Kingdom", id: "uk", idToShow: [ 1,2 ] }
],
```

At the end you will change your template in this way:

```
<div class="" v-for="field in fields" :key="field.id" v-if="idToShowMain.includes(field.id)">
```

In this way you could remove the `show` property from each field.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I did the same. But how to listen particular idToShow in onChage() event in the select tag i.e, @change="onChange(....)"